# Change the conection limit of PostgreSQL on IBM-Cloud

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, ibm-cloud

On IBM-Cloud it is not possible to change the connection limit of a PostgreSQL. I only have 100 connections and I could use some more.

There is no point inside the documentation: [Compose for PostgreSQL documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/ComposeForPostgreSQL/dashboard-settings.html#settings)

Before there was the following possibility: [original compose documentation](https://www.compose.com/articles/compose-notes-postgresql-connection-limit-control/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it seems not possible at the very moment. I have to create a ticket so that the support can adjust the setting.